# Changing the id parameter in Rails routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3

Using Ruby on Rails 3's new routing system, is it possible to change the default :id parameter

```
resources :users, :key => :username
```

come out with the following routes

```
/users/new
/users/:username
/users/:username/edit
...etc
```

I'm asking because although the above example is simple, it would be really helpful to do in a current project I'm working on.

Is it possible to change this parameter, and if not, is there a particular reason as to why not?

Comment: I like this question from the perspective of "How do I change the default ID used to fetch a user/object/etc.?"  However, I just want to put a plug in for obscuring that default ID as it tends to be a Primary Key directly from the database and there are all sorts of security reasons why you should not expose that value (easing SQL injection attacks, guessable IDs for other users, …).  In particular, using the username enables direct attack on an account (pwd guessing). Using a large random and unique value makes all of these a lot harder. Cheers.

Comment: *Make sure to read the answers after the accepted one*

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you want is to have the `username` instead of `id` in your url, right?

You can do that by overriding the `to_param` method in your model. You can get more information [**here**](http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url).

Comment: I guess this is the only way to go about it for now.  Seems kind of roundabout though.

Comment: Thanks for this pointer, completely solved my problem. I came here looking for how to change this b/c, by policy, we consider fetching by Primary Key ID from web as a security issue. Instead, we add a large random and unique value to the object (SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(15)) and use that as the ID returned from to_param and when the RESTful APIs find_by_OID. Perhaps, when I understand ruby/rails better, this can be made into a gem.

Answer (score 73):

In your route you can use

```
resources :user, param: :username
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, I'm much more comfortable adding an argument to a route than I am overwriting the `to_param` method

Comment: @omnikron it depends on what you trying to achive in your app, sometimes you need to do both (e.g. when you want directly pass your resource to routing helpers `user_path @user` so that you don't have to do `user_path @user.username`) ...but yes you're right, this is elegant when you just want routing functionality.

Answer (score 30):

For Ruby on Rails 4.1.4 (and possibly earlier versions) you need to do what **both** [j..](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2838095/2700898) and [Ujjwal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20773186/2700898) suggested:

1) In `config/routes.rb`, add:

```
resources :user, param: :username
```

2) In `app/models/user.rb`, add:

```
def to_param
  username
end
```

In you only do #1 then all your routes will be correct, as can be seen from `rake routes`:

```
$ rake routes
    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
user_index GET    /user(.:format)                user#index
           POST   /user(.:format)                user#create
  new_user GET    /user/new(.:format)            user#new
 edit_user GET    /user/:username/edit(.:format) user#edit
      user GET    /user/:username(.:format)      user#show
           PATCH  /user/:username(.:format)      user#update
           PUT    /user/:username(.:format)      user#update
           DELETE /user/:username(.:format)      user#destroy
```

However the helper methods that construct a url based on a `User` instance will still include the `id` in the url, e.g. `/user/1`. To get the `username` in the constructed urls, you need to override [`to_param`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param) as in #2.

Comment: the 2) is most of the time missed when when this question appears; this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer has been accepted by the asker, but there is a simple approach to do this. Write this code in your controller.

```
authorize_resource :find_by => :username
```

and in your view, where you want to show the link, write this code.

```
<%= link_to "Username", user_path(u.username) %>
```

You don't need any other changes in your routes or controller.

**UPDATE:** This will only work if you are using CanCan gem.

Comment: That appears to be a CanCan method. Its not mentioned in the rails api at all. [apidock.com](http://apidock.com/rails/search?query=authorize_resource) [api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/?q=authorize_resource)

Comment: Yes, that is a CanCan method. I forgot to mention that in my answer. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the user name as the input to the path helpers.

In your view code:

```
user_path(u.username) #/users/john
```

In your controller treat the `id` received as `username`:

```
def show
  user = User.find_by_username!(params[:id])
  ...
end
```

Comment: That's kind of what I've been doing, but I just think it'd be more straightforward to do something like User.find_by_username(params[:username]) in the code.  I really am just wondering why Rails doesn't allow this in general.  Is it against some REST principle perhaps?