# Use multiple routes for same objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In Rails the default routes use the internal database id to identify the resource, so you end up with routes like:

```
/user/1/widget/4
```

It's possible to change these to use something other than `:id` [easily enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837102/changing-the-id-parameter-in-rails-routing) so that you could have routes like:

```
/user/bob/widget/favorites
```

But is there a way to have both available? I ask because in my case I'm using the route to create a unique id for use with an external service, but I'd like them to be based on a field other than `id` because it's more useful to pass these alternative ids to the external service.

I can of course build something custom, but we currently have some code that works as follows (with other convenience functions on top; this is the core functionality) to get most of the functionality I would have to build 'for free' from Rails:

```
class PathIdParser
  def initialize
    @context = Application.routes
  end

  def parse(path)
    @context.recognize_path(path)
  end

  def build(route, params)
    @context.named_routes[route].format(params)
  end
end
```

Obviously the `build` function is easy enough to work with to use other routes by just changing the values passed into the `params` hash, but is there a way I can get `parse` to use these alternative fields to look up resources by, since `recognize_path` seems to work based on the values returned by `to_param`.

Answer (score 0):

In routes.rb

```
get 'user/:username/widget/favourites', to: 'users#favourites'
```

This would route 'user/bob/widget/favourites' to the favourites action of the UsersController and you could access the username via

```
@username = params[:username]
```

Comment: So while it is possible to just add additional routes, I'd prefer not to have to do this and instead try to get my second set of additional routes automatically generated the way they would be if I were to set `to_param`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method to_param() in your model.

It returns a String, which Action Pack uses for constructing an URL to this object. The default implementation returns this record’s id as a String, or nil if this record’s unsaved.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param  
    name
  end
end

user = User.find_by_name('Richard')

user_path(user)  # => "/users/Richard"
```