# Ruby on Rails page control

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-deployment

I'm sorry, my English is bad. Question: I have model Pages with columns title, description etc. I can create, change, destroy these pages. I can see the contents of the link `mydomain/pages/1`. I need for each page has been template and route, so I can see the content on the link, for example `maydomain/contacts`. How to do it? Help me please.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem.

Answer (score 0):

One way to implement your own solution is to add this to your routes file:

`get '/mydomain/:slug, to: 'pages#show'`

This is a pretty general matcher, so add it to the bottom of your routes so it doesn't override others.

Then your controller show action will look something like:

```
def show
  @page = Page.find_by_slug(params[:slug])
end
```

This of course assumes you have a slug column on your Pages table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by "mydomain" you mean the root url of your site (e.g. myapp.example.com)

I'd suggest that you separate the problem into two parts:

1. Use an attribute other than id to identify an item in the url
2. Reduce the route so that the controller does not need to be specified.

For 1, have a look at this: [Rails routes with :name instead of :id url parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226378/rails-routes-with-name-instead-of-id-url-parameters) Note, that as @spickermann suggests [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) could be a good solution for you.

For 2, you will need to create a route without the controller name, and then specify the controller in the route definition. (See the [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources)):

```
get ':param', to: :show, controller: 'pages'
```

For that to work, you will need to put it after (lower in routes.rb) so that it doesn't intefer with other routes. I'd also recommend [adding a constraint to the route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) - to limit the wrong urls that could be routed to that rout.