# change routes URL from a random :id to :username in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I want to change my routes.rb file in a way so that it changes my current urls

```
 localhost:3000/amitian/1
```

to localhost:3000/username

I will provide my routes.rb file for reference

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do

 devise_for :amitians

 root 'home#index'
 resources :amitians do
 member do
 get :following, :followers
 end
end
 resources :confessions do
member do
    get 'like' , to: 'confessions#upvote'
    get 'dislike' , to: 'confessions#downvote'
    end
    resources :confessioncomments
  end
    resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]

 end
```

Comment: This question is very similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226378/rails-routes-with-name-instead-of-id-url-parameters which suggests to use friendly_id

Comment: I don't feel friendly_id gem is something I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Gregg mentioned, you can change the name of the parameter using:

`resources :amitians, param: :username`

But you're essentially just renaming a variable. Whether you expect an id or a username is determined in the controller action amitians#show:

```
@amitian = Amitian.find(param[:id]) # Treat :id as id
@amitian = Amitian.find_by_username(param[:id]) # Treat :id as username
```

Now, if you want to specifically route to `/:username` rather than `/amitians/:username`, you'll have to override that resource route:

```
resources :amitians, except: [:show] do
  member do
    get :following, :followers
  end
end
get '/:username', to: 'amitians#show'
```

However, I would recommend against that. Having a parameter directly off root will cause lots of confusion for you when users type in the incorrect url and get a user page instead of a 404 error. Or even worse, what if a user chooses the username 'login' or 'register'? Either your register page would be unreachable or else that user's page would be.

I should also point out that rails convenience methods such as `resources`, `Amitian.find`, `url_for @amitian`, `link_to @amitian` etc. all use the REST standard which uses numerical IDs.

If you want to use a username instead of IDs, you'll have to stop relying on these methods and change your controllers and views, in addition to your routes file.

Answer (score 0):

In rails 4 you can do the following in the route

```
resources :amitians, param: :username
```

Comment: I tried that  but that didn't change anything url is still the same