# How do I build a link_to tag that takes a string ID instead of a numeric id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, link-to

I have a routes question concerning Rails 5.  I have this in my config/routes.rb file

```
  resources :votes
```

The "show" method in my VotesController can take an ID of either a numeric or string form.

```
  def show
    id = params[:id]
    if id.present?
      # If they entered a name
      if id.to_i == 0
        name = id.gsub "_", " "
        @person = Person.find_by_name(name)
      else
        @person = Person.find_by_id(id)
      end
```

I used to be able to construct this link_to to link to the method to generate a link with a numeric ID ...

```
<%= link_to person.name, vote_path(person), :class => 'unvotedPersonLink' %>
```

However, I would like to generate a link with a string value for the ID, as defined by a method in my model called "person.seo_name".  So I tried this

```
<%= link_to person.name, vote_path(:id => person.seo_name), :class => 'unvotedPersonLink' %>
```

but got the error

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"votes", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

How can I build my link_to tag so that it passes in my desired "string" parameter instead of a numeric one?

Comment: make sure seo_name mehod is not returning nil

Comment: `vote_path(:id => person.seo_name)` should work as long as `seo_name` has a value. Try commenting out all other routes except `resources :votes` to see if another route definition is interfering.

Comment: You should just be able to do `vote_path(person.seo_name)` ... you don't need to (and shouldn't) specify `:id =>...` as that means the first parameter(the linked object) is `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in whatever you want. If the error is telling you that the ID you're passing is `nil`, then your `seo_name` attribute for the `Person` you're using is `nil`.

As long as `vote_path` is expecting an ID, which you can check via `rake routes | grep vote`, then this will work fine for you as far as generating a link goes:

```
<%= link_to person.name, vote_path(person.seo_name) %>
```

But keep in mind that it'll require you to make the necessary adjustments in your controller to search your `persons` table based on the `seo_name` column, instead of `id`.

---

Also, I highly recommend that you [utilize a gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) called `friendly_id` for what you're trying to accomplish. It'll make things a lot cleaner and DRYer, as you can use it easily in any model. And you can easily use either the ID *or* a URL-friendly slug to query your table, simply by adding `friendly` to the query:

```
Person.friendly.find(1)

# OR #

Person.friendly.find('this-is-a-url-friendly-string')
```

Comment: I tried changing my "vote_path(person)" block to what you have -- "vote_path(person.seo_name)", but I still get the error, "No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"votes", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]".

Comment: I have verified through debugging that "person.seo_name" is indeed not nil.

Answer (score 0):

In your view

```
<%= link_to person.name, vote_path(person), :class => 'unvotedPersonLink' %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to person.name, vote_path(id: person.seo_name), :class => 'unvotedPersonLink' %>
```

in your controller

```
@person = Person.find_by(id: params[:id]) || Person.find_by(name: params[:id])
```

make sure seo_name method is not returning nil

Comment: Am I supposed to be doing something with my config/routes.rb file?  When I put in "<%= link_to person.name, vote_path(id: person.seo_name), :class => 'unvotedPersonLink' %>", I get the error, "No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"votes", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]" upon loading the page.

Comment: is your controller name spaced?

Comment: The votes controller?  THe file path is "app/controllers/votes_controller.rb" and the first line in the file reads "class VotesController < ApplicationController".

Comment: No @Natalia you do not need to do anything with your route. Just make sure in your database person do have seo_name. If it doesn't then this error will come.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is coming from `vote_path`, so we can focus on that and not worry about `link_to` or the controller.

When I'm having route problems like this, the first thing I do is run `rake routes` (or nowadays `rails routes`) to make sure I've got the right name. Second I play around in the console with the `app` variable. For example:

```
> app.vote_path(1)
 => "/votes/1"
> app.vote_path(id: 1)
 => "/votes/1"
> app.vote_path("foo")
 => "/votes/foo"
> app.vote_path(id: "foo")
 => "/votes/foo"
> app.vote_path(nil)
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"votes", :id=>nil}, possible unmatched constraints: [:id]
> app.vote_path(id: nil)
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"votes", :id=>nil}, possible unmatched constraints: [:id]
```

You say elsewhere you've checked already that `person.seo_name` is not returning nil, but I would check again, but it really looks like that's the problem. Try this:

```
p = Person.find 5   # or whatever is the numeric id
app.vote_path(p.seo_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

The params can contain any information, but you have to process them in the controller based on your need. By default, the routes requires to have an params called `:id`. If you want other name to be used in your route you can override the default resource identifier :id

Check the [rails routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters)

Make sure the `person.seo_name` is not returning `nil`. So, you can use `before_save` callback in `Person` model. There, you can set the `seo_name` field with specific data.

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_save :populate_seo_name, on: :create

   private
     def populate_seo_name
       self.seo_name = ...
     end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

This has been answered in the past https://stackoverflow.com/a/26600064/4652075.

You are passing a string to a field that is expecting an integer and it is being rendered null. You should be passing a string value to a field that is expecting a string. If your "votes" model is generated by [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) then it is likely an integer.

In your case:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  def to_param
    identifier
  end

  # or
  alias_method :to_param, :identifier
end

class VotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_voter

  def show end;

  private

  def set_voter
    if !params[:id]?
      @person = Person.find_by(identifier: params[:seo_name])
    else
      @person = Person.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
end

# in the view
<%= link_to person.name, votes_path(identifier: person.seo_name), class: "whatever" %>
```

Should work.