# Access to URL general URL paramter instead of :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

To handle requests to /pizzas/marinara I could use

```
get '/pizzas/marinara', to: 'pizzas#marinara'
```

However, if there are lots of different kinds of pizzas it makes sense to introduce a corresponding variable. I know that

```
get '/pizzas/:id', to: 'pizzas#show'
```

makes the id available in the show action of the pizzas controller as params[:id]. For example, if someone visits /pizzas/3, params[:id] will yield 3.

Is it possible to use something like

```
get '/pizzas/:pizzaname', to: 'pizzas#show'
```

to access the :pizzaname in the show action of the pizzas controller, i.e. as params[:pizzaname]?

(I found several related questions, but they all seemed to be concerned with resources whereas I'm trying to figure this out in more explicit terms for just out route.)

Comment: this topic should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226378/rails-routes-with-name-instead-of-id-url-parameters . Easiest way is to use gem friendly_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a string you're really just creating a pattern that rails will match the incoming URL to. `:id` is just a [dynamic segment](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments) in that pattern so whatever name you use for the segment will be mapped to the parameters hash:

```
get '/pizzas/:foo(/:bar)(/:baz)', to: 'pizzas#show'
```

In this route we added two extra optional dynamic segments so `/pizzas/exotic/hawaii/with_extra_pineapple` you would give you the following parameters hash:

```
{
  "controller"=>"pizzas", 
  "action"=>"show", 
  "foo"=>"exotic", 
  "bar"=>"hawaii", 
  "baz"=>"with_extra_pineapple"
}
```

You can also customize the name of the id parameter when using the [resources](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resources) macro by passing the `param` option:

```
resources :pizzas, param: :pizza_name
```

However as always when breaking with convention you really need to ask yourself if you're just being a kook and if it actually serves any real purpose. My guess here is that the answer is no since you can add "friendly urls" without changing the name of the parameter.