# Why is my param being ignored in a Controller for a show view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

When I visit:

URL/salvage/25605

ActiveRecord shows an error RecordNotFound

**Couldn't find Salvage without an ID**

**Parameters:**
`{"id"=>"25605"}`

Why is ActiveRecord searching for "id" when I included "typeID" in the params?

### Controller

```
class SalvageController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @salvage = Salvage.find(params[:typeID])
  end
```

### Model

```
class Salvage < ApplicationRecord
  validates :typeID, presence: true
  validates :amount, presence: true
end
```

### View

```
<%= @salvage.typeID %>, <%= @salvage.amount %>
```

### Resources

```
resources :salvage
```

### Rails Routes

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                                       Controller#Action
                             salvage_new GET    /salvage/new(.:format)                                                                            salvage#new
                                    root GET    /                                                                                                 application#hello
                production_pages_copying GET    /production_pages/copying(.:format)                                                               production_pages#copying
                           salvage_index GET    /salvage(.:format)                                                                                salvage#index
                                         POST   /salvage(.:format)                                                                                salvage#create
                             new_salvage GET    /salvage/new(.:format)                                                                            salvage#new
                            edit_salvage GET    /salvage/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                       salvage#edit
                                 salvage GET    /salvage/:id(.:format)                                                                            salvage#show
                                         PATCH  /salvage/:id(.:format)                                                                            salvage#update
                                         PUT    /salvage/:id(.:format)                                                                            salvage#update
                                         DELETE /salvage/:id(.:format)                                                                            salvage#destroy
```

I am following the ruby on rails 6th edition tutorial on learnenough.com a second time around using my own data

Comment: Can you add the result for `rake routes | grep salvage` and request params from rails server log

Comment: aha! 'salvage GET /salvage/:id(.:format)' @DeepakMahakale interesting...

Comment: by the way rake routes was depreciated in rails 6.1 in favor of rails routes https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/41ad613e4c5d6c05f20ac0437564ff0d31ab9f5a

Comment: @DeepakMahakale I have included the results of rails routes in the original question

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Deepak Mahakale I ran the rails routes command and noticed `:id(format)` was added at the end of the GET route.

I searched stack overflow for questions regarding changing `:id(format)` to something else and came across:

[Changing the id parameter in Rails routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837102/changing-the-id-parameter-in-rails-routing)

I thus changed my Resources in the router to:

```
resources :salvage, param: :typeID
```

The show view now works albeit rather slow
I shall do some more research on the topic of resources to gain a clearer understanding.

I hope this answer proves useful to anyone who may stumble upon the same question

Comment: Just a hint, but `type_id` is the ruby convention, using snake_case

Comment: thanks for the hint @Eyeslandic! I used the name from the csv I'm using - I'll bear that in mind for my next run through!